# How to get one last row from repeating rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have One SQL query to retrieve the previous date record. I want to select last record from repeating rows, How can I do this?
My query is as below.

```
Declare @previous datetime
Set @previous = (select dateadd(day, -1, '20180216'))
select  MstSmartItemLedger.smartitemid,MstSmartItemLedger.ItemCode,Balanceqty 
from MstSmartItemLedger 
where (CONVERT(Nvarchar, MstSmartItemLedger.SDate, 112) = @previous)
```

And I got results like this

```
smartitemid itemcode balanceqty
    802       1141    -3
    803       118     -13
    804       1110    -24
    805       112     -21
    806       115    -24
    807       11141   -5
    808       1127    -21
    809       1129     -4
    810       11129   -181
    811       1139    -179
    812       1134     -32
    813       11103     -3
    814       1199      -6
    815       11102    -7
    816       11129    -183
    817       1188     -18
    818       1189      -11
    819       1139     -180
    820       117      -43
    821       114      -34
    822       1155     -20
    823       11140    -58
    824       1188     -22
    825       1188     -22
    826       1111     -11
```

As above results there is two rows of itemcode 11129 so I want last record of smartitemid 816. I want result as below

```
smartitemid itemcode balanceqty
        802       1141    -3
        803       118     -13
        804       1110    -24
        805       112     -21
        806       115    -24
        807       11141   -5
        808       1127    -21
        809       1129     -4
        812       1134     -32
        813       11103     -3
        814       1199      -6
        815       11102    -7
        816       11129    -183
        818       1189      -11
        819       1139     -180
        820       117      -43
        821       114      -34
        822       1155     -20
        823       11140    -58
        825       1188     -22
        826       1111     -11
```

How can I get this result? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`  clause with `max()`..`min()` aggregation function

```
SELECT
       MAX(smartitemid) smartitemid, itemcode, MIN(balanceqty) balanceqty
FROM MstSmartItemLedger m
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, SDate, 112) = @previous
GROUP BY itemcode
ORDER BY 1
```

Probably *look-up* table will also usefull

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM MstSmartItemLedger m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(smartitemid) smartitemid 
    FROM MstSmartItemLedger
    WHERE CONVERT(varchar, SDate, 112) = @previous 
    GROUP BY itemcode
)a ON a.smartitemid = m.smartitemid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Declare @previous datetime
Set @previous = (select dateadd(day, -1, '20180216'))

SELECT  MstSmartItemLedger.smartitemid,MstSmartItemLedger.ItemCode,Balanceqty 
FROM MstSmartItemLedger
WHERE MstSmartItemLedger.smartitemid IN(
    select  MAX(MstSmartItemLedger.smartitemid)
    from MstSmartItemLedger 
        where (CONVERT(Nvarchar, MstSmartItemLedger.SDate, 112) = @previous)
    GROUP BY MstSmartItemLedger.ItemCode
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group it on the itemcode and take max smartitemid you should get the list as you like

```
Declare @previous datetime
Set @previous = (select dateadd(day, -1, '20180216'))
select  MAX(MstSmartItemLedger.smartitemid) smartitemid, MstSmartItemLedger.ItemCode, Balanceqty 
from MstSmartItemLedger 
where (CONVERT(Nvarchar, MstSmartItemLedger.SDate, 112) = @previous)
GROUP BY MstSmartItemLedger.ItemCode, Balanceqty
```